# Python file contents printed when called from HTML instead of result

Tags: python, html, cgi

I've got two files, index.html and form.py in my C:\Apache24\htdocs directory on Windows 10. The contents are as follows:

index.html

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>demo web file python2.7</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form name="pyform" method="POST" action="/form.py">  
  <input type="text" name="fname" />  
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

form.py

```
#!C:\Python27/python
print "Content-Type: text/html"      

import cgi,cgitb  
cgitb.enable() #for debugging  
form = cgi.FieldStorage()  
name = form.getvalue('fname')  
print "Name of the user is:",name
```

The Apache server is configured to run cgi scripts with the following settings:

```
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"
<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
```

When I populate the text area and click "Submit" button on the page, I get the entire contents of the python file on the resulting page, instead of what I had put into the box.

What is missing or what am I doing wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: I'm missing a **New line** after `print('Content-Type...` but that's not related to your Problem. Apache don't accept `form.py` as a CGI, therefore instead of _**executing**_ show the content of the File.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark `htdocs` as set aside for CGI programs by using `ScriptAlias` directive.

```
ScriptAlias "C:/Apache24/htdocs"
```

#### References:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias

Comment: That didn't change anything. I allowed my root dir to be accessed, therefore I don't need to alias another directory.

Comment: Yeah, you need to `ScriptAlias` any directory with files you will like to do CGI execution on except `DocumentRoo`. Is the CGI module loaded? LoadModule `cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so`

Comment: I don't have any directories other than DocumentRoot, this is just for development. Module is loaded.